# Comparing Dates by Fixed Level of Detail in mySQL

Tags: mysql, date, partitioning, rolling-computation, level-of-detail

Good Morning,

I'm trying to create a mySQL query with the following output:

[image: Click here to view desired table output]

In order to get the 60_days_since_seen, I need to compare the reference_date for the current row to the next most recent reference_date relative to the unique_identifier and determine if that reference_date is older than 60 days from the reference_date from that row.

Ex: unique_identifier = 123456789

id = 1: Since there is no date before this instance, the 60_days_since_seen is TRUE (or 1).

id = 2: Since the date of the reference_date occurrence prior to this id relative to the unique_identifier is less than 60 days since this row's reference_date, the 60_days_since_seen is FALSE (or 0).

id = 3: Since the date of the reference_date occurrence prior to this id relative to the unique_identifier is greater than 60 days since this row's reference_date, the 60_days_since_seen is TRUE (or 1).

id = 4: Since there is no date before this instance, the 60_days_since_seen is TRUE (or 1).

id = 5: Since the date of the reference_date occurrence prior to this id relative to the unique_identifier is less than 60 days since this row's reference_date, the 60_days_since_seen is FALSE (or 0).

Comment: which mysql version are you using?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first query works also with mysql 5.x.

The second uses window functions that are only supported in mysql 8

> ```
> CREATE TABLE datetable (
>   `Id` INTEGER,
>   `unique_identifier` INTEGER,
>   `reference_date` Date
> );
>
> INSERT INTO datetable
>   (`Id`, `unique_identifier`, `reference_date`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '123456789', '2020-01-05'),
>   ('2', '123456789', '2020-02-20'),
>   ('3', '123456789', '2020-06-29'),
>   ('4', '987654321', '2020-02-21'),
>   ('5', '987654321', '2020-03-30');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> `Id`, `reference_date`
> ,IF(@unique_identifier = `unique_identifier`,IF(DATEDIFF(`reference_date`,@date) > 60,1,0),1) 60_days_since_seen
> ,@unique_identifier := `unique_identifier` as 'unique_identifier'
> ,@date :=`reference_date` 'reference_date'
> FROM
> (SELECT * FROM datetable ORDER BY unique_identifier,reference_date) t1
> ,(SELECT @unique_identifier := 0) a,(SELECT @date := NOW()) b
> ```
>
> ```
> Id | reference_date | 60_days_since_seen | unique_identifier | reference_date
> -: | :------------- | -----------------: | ----------------: | :-------------
>  1 | 2020-01-05     |                  1 |         123456789 | 2020-01-05    
>  2 | 2020-02-20     |                  0 |         123456789 | 2020-02-20    
>  3 | 2020-06-29     |                  1 |         123456789 | 2020-06-29    
>  4 | 2020-02-21     |                  1 |         987654321 | 2020-02-21    
>  5 | 2020-03-30     |                  0 |         987654321 | 2020-03-30
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> `Id`, `unique_identifier`, `reference_date`,
>    IF(DATEDIFF(reference_date , LAG(reference_date) OVER (
>         PARTITION BY unique_identifier
>         ORDER BY reference_date ))> 60 OR LAG(reference_date) OVER (
>         PARTITION BY unique_identifier
>         ORDER BY reference_date ) is NULL,1,0) 60_days_since_seen
> FROM datetable
> ```
>
> ```
> Id | unique_identifier | reference_date | 60_days_since_seen
> -: | ----------------: | :------------- | -----------------:
>  1 |         123456789 | 2020-01-05     |                  1
>  2 |         123456789 | 2020-02-20     |                  0
>  3 |         123456789 | 2020-06-29     |                  1
>  4 |         987654321 | 2020-02-21     |                  1
>  5 |         987654321 | 2020-03-30     |                  0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=63e82e89280391ed8483bd4f7aea237e)*